# Send pre-written email from template with recipient's name in body of text

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I send emails with an attachment with not much in the body of the text.

I'd like a way of entering the following:

> To FirstName
>
> Please see attached.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> WillacyMe

All email addresses are structured FirstName.LastName@company.com.

I need a way to add FirstName to the body of a text.

The following VBA code opens up a template:

```
Sub QuickAttachementTemplate()

    Set temp = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\WillacyMe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\AttachmentTemplate.oft")
    temp.Display
    Set temp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This has a space to add the FirstName and I add the email address after running the macro.

Is there a way to enter an email address in a new email and then run the macro?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I've expanded up on my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the FirstName placeholder with text parsed from the email address.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplacePlaceholder()

    Dim tempReplacePlaceholder As MailItem
    Dim recipAddress As String
    Dim firstNameFromAddress As String
    Dim len_firstNameFromAddress As Long

    ' Generate mailitem with placeholder "FirstName"
    ' Enter a single recipient in the To field
    Set tempReplacePlaceholder = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    tempReplacePlaceholder.Save

    With tempReplacePlaceholder
        recipAddress = .To
        Debug.Print recipAddress

        ' All email addresses must be structured FirstName.LastName@company.com.
        ' Find first instance of "."
        len_firstNameFromAddress = InStr(recipAddress, ".") - 1
        Debug.Print len_firstNameFromAddress

        firstNameFromAddress = Left(recipAddress, len_firstNameFromAddress)
        Debug.Print firstNameFromAddress
        .Body = Replace(.Body, "FirstName", firstNameFromAddress)
        .Display

    End With

End Sub
```