# Outlook Templates and the way to work with them dynamically

Tags: java, vba, outlook

How to create and manage multiple fillable email templates with data insertion fields in Microsoft Outlook for dynamic sending via SMTP from my Java service?

I have a Java service that sends email via SMTP. I need to efficiently create and manage multiple email templates in Outlook, each of which contains fields for inserting data. Can these templates include HTML markup, and how can they be dynamically populated with data?

Comment: If you already have Outlook, why not send through Outlook? And if you use Outlook as a template editor (what format do you save the items in Outlook?), why not simply take HTML files no matter where they were produced in?

Comment: See [replacing placeholders in html template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63567445/vba-replacing-all-placeholders-in-outlook-html-template-with-userform-textbox-an), [Edit placeholders in Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61693768/edit-placeholders-in-outlook-template-file-oft), [Send email from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270493/send-pre-written-email-from-template-with-recipients-name-in-body-of-text) and [Replace multiple values in Outlook mail htmlbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503752/replace-multiple-values-in-outlook-mail-htmlbody).